# Unable to connect to mysql database with mysql-connector-python with created users

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-connector-python

I have a big problem connecting users with MySQL-connector. I don't know if it's important for me to say this but I'm with a docker-container.

As you can see at the bottom left of the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TH0W.png) I have users that I created using the MySQL console or directly with the SQL code.

I've already tried to do things I've seen on other stackoverflow questions and in the doc. Then, I came to this code to be able to create a user but unfortunately, it still doesn't work :

```sql
CREATE USER 'user2'@localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'UserPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user2'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You have to know that I can connect with the admin and root account that there is in my docker-compose.

Comment: Can you run this command ```SELECT user FROM mysql.user;``` and check whether the user is listed or not.

Comment: @LavSharma Yes, user2 is listed [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/626838080669614110/838325921735507968/unknown.png)

Comment: Can you check ```SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user2'@'localhost';``` and similarly for ```root```. 
Or maybe try changing the password once using ```UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('[password]') WHERE User='[user2]';
``` and then check reconnecting.

Comment: User2 has the same privileges than root but when I do the second command I have an syntax error : ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('password') WHERE User='user2'' at line 1```

Comment: ```UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='user2';``` and then ```FLUSH PRIVILEGES;```

Comment: I still have the same error ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('MyNewPass') WHERE User='user2'' at line 1```

Comment: ```UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('password') WHERE user='user2';
```

Comment: I still have a syntax error : ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('password') WHERE user='user2'' at line 1```
Thanks for your help you could save my student project

Comment: If you want you can get in touch with me https://github.com/lavsharmaa/lavsharmaa/issues/ so that we can debug it nicely. Here it would just increase the number of comments.